# Making a 25” deep butcher block counter deeper

Tags: joinery

I am looking to install a butcherblock countertop in my kitchen but can only find 25” depth which is only 1/4” overhang. Can I add a strip of wood to the back of it to widen it?  Or perhaps make a trim around the front?  Best way to do this?

Comment: Hi welcome to SE. Please give us more to go on. At heart you're asking can you join wood to wood, so of course the generic answer is yes. But the specifics matter in terms of what's doable/advisable. Has the wood been treated with finish yet, if so with what? (If oiled, that's a problem.) What's the existing wood? Can you get more of whatever it is? How important is it that you get a good species/colour match? (Can be easy, can be hard, depending. And assumes you can separately buy more of a given species.)

Comment: Last but not least, are you a woodworker? If you're not one already this may be basically impossible, regardless of whether it can be done on paper. If you had to buy from scratch the tools needed to process even one plank of wood from a lumber/timber supplier and then join it to the existing counter material basically make this not economically viable, *and that's even with taking clamps out of the equation* (you can clamp with twine or rope if you have to, or just use nails or screws so no actual clamping is needed).

Comment: The best way is easy: hire a cabinet maker or installer, or be or become one! As suggested in another comment, there are other considerations for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Adding piece in front probably means you need to remove a little material to get rid of rounding and since you will probably want use glue, you need to expose bare wood.
It seems like adding at back is easier, since you can use screws - no need to remove material. Also added wood piece can be shaped to match wall irregularities (instead of shaping whole countertop).

Comment: Not to mention that a bit at the back is must less visible than at the front (although you can make trim at the front a feature, so it doesn't need to blend in).

Answer (score 0):

McMaster Carr sells butcher block up to 36" deep. They are found under wood workbench tops, but are safe for food service. I've had my hands on many of them in maple, and they are just what you want in a butcher block.

Comment: Hi welcome to SE. This is a great alternative for the OP, assuming they can order from McMaster Carr. Unfortunately it's likely we won't ever hear back from them so we'll never know.